# Terraform how to skip argument for 1 workspace

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

Is it possible to skip 1 argument for 1 workspace in terraform?

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "appgw" {
  name                = var.appgw
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  location            = var.location
  **zones = var.aks_zones**
  sku {
    name = var.app_gateway_sku
    tier = var.app_gateway_tier
  }
```

I am setting a DR environment in a region where availability zones are not supported, so for the script to pass the "Zones" argument needs to be skipped for one workspace only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I added an `availability_zone = "No-Zone"` argument to my AppGW IP address block.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `azurerm_application_gateway` resource's `zones` variable is Optional ([source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/application_gateway#zones)), you can set the default value for your `aks_zones` variable to `null`:

```
variable "aks_zones" {
  default = null
}
```

This way, you can skip specifying the `aks_zones` variable for your one workspace while setting a value for the other workspaces.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but my variable for my zones is setup as:

type = list(number) 

There for "null" will through back an error.

Comment: I see - try `default = []` in that case

Comment: After adding default = [] I still receive an error stating "locationNotSupportAvailabilityZones".

Is there a way for terraform (maybe using locals?) to just bypass this argument?

Comment: `null` is actually a valid value of type `list(number)`, at least in this context of variable type constraints, so setting the default to `null` _should_ work, and should get the desired effect of omitting the `zones` argument in the resource configuration because omitted resource arguments are always `null` and so the provider can't see the difference between those two values. (But it can see the difference between `null` and an empty list, and hence generate the error you saw.)

Comment: null is working as a value but I still receive the same error message.